# SAP Webi document to Excel, other values have no decimal place

Tags: excel, webi

I am working with SAP BOBI 4.1. My issue is when I export a Webi document to Excel, other values have no decimal place.Please advise regarding this. Thank you.

Formula used:
ToNumber(FormatNumber([obj];"#.0000")

Output in the program:
1

Expected output:
1.0000

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to achieve this in number format but if you use only

```
FormatNumber([obj];"#.0000")
```

You should have "1.0000" in excel but in text format.